# How to repeat a numpy array on both axis?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2d array, lets say the array is:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
```

I want it to repeat 3 times on both axis, so it will look like:

```
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6
4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6
4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6
```

Ive tried using numpy.repeat but unsuccessful.
any suggestions? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the kronicker product, `np.kron` and a `ones` array of the size of the block.

```
a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3) + 1
np.kron(a, np.ones((3,3), dtype = a.dtype))

Out[]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6],
       [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6],
       [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]])
```

Comment: this is nice, but how can i keep my array the same dtype?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `numpy repeat`

```py
>>> data = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
>>> data
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> np.repeat(data,[3,3,3],axis=1).repeat([3,3],axis=0)
array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6],
       [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6],
       [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]])
```